# Can JQuery Form Wizard submit 'pages' that haven't been shown?

Tags: jquery, formwizard

I'm using the JQuery Form Wizard plugin without a final AJAX submit, just a regular POST. Using AJAX isn't feasible due to the complexity of the final form processing code.

The problem is that on an error I need to redisplay the form, and jump the user to the correct page with formwizard('show', 'spanid' ). The problem is that then the wizard counts all the other steps as not viewed and doesn't re-submit their input values when the user re-submits.

I have considered copying all the other inputs into the page being displayed as hidden fields but really this isn't feasible, there are too many complex variables involved.

Does anyone know if it's possible to instruct the plugin to submit all inputs regardless of whether they're on a skipped page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question but so far what I found is you want to submit the for regardless of validation.

In form wizard you can use "formOptions" property to define your own submition.

even if its not ajax you can simply use some script to redirect.

Hope it helps :-)

Reards,
 Amjad

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm using the built-in support for non-AJAX submission. I tried a few hacks on the library but couldn't get it to work reliably, so instead I re-designed some of the validation code to remove the requirement.

Comment: @Tolan Hi! did you solve this? Im having the same problem :/ skipping steps are not submitted. Is there a workaround? Thanks in advanced.